# Cannot Start Jupyter IPython Notebook Kernel

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, sage

I'm using Jupyter Notebooks from VSCode.

I'm having issues starting my Python (Sagemath) Kernel. The error text (when running the cell in VSCode) is as follows:

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
unknown option --python
usage: /root/anaconda3/envs/sage/bin/python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information. 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

This is a snippet from the log file:

```
warn 16:18:12.373: Kernel Error, context = start [ap [Error]: The kernel died. Error: unknown option --python
usage: /root/anaconda3/envs/sage/bin/python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2000312134/out/extension.node.js:17:102857)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)] {
  category: 'kerneldied',
  kernelConnectionMetadata: Zd {
    kind: 'startUsingPythonInterpreter',
    kernelSpec: {
      specFile: '/root/anaconda3/envs/sage/share/jupyter/kernels/sagemath/kernel.json',
      interpreterPath: '/root/anaconda3/envs/sage/bin/python',
      isRegisteredByVSC: 'registeredByNewVersionOfExtForCustomKernelSpec',
      name: 'pythonjvsc74a57bd0fbfe4b38fd9276f8fd065521985c9d949b01305ee70753a4e78b421b898ddb3e',
      argv: [Array],
      language: 'sage',
      executable: '/root/anaconda3/envs/sage/bin/sage',
      display_name: 'SageMath 9.7',
      metadata: [Object]
    },
    interpreter: {
      id: '/root/anaconda3/envs/sage/bin/python',
      sysPrefix: '/root/anaconda3/envs/sage',
      envPath: [f],
      displayPath: [Object],
      envName: 'sage',
      displayName: 'sage',
      envType: 'Conda',
      version: [Object],
      uri: [f]
    },
    id: '.jvsc74a57bd0fbfe4b38fd9276f8fd065521985c9d949b01305ee70753a4e78b421b898ddb3e#sagemath./root/anaconda3/envs/sage/python././root/anaconda3/envs/sage/bin/sage#--python#-m#sage.repl.ipython_kernel#-f#{connection_file}'
  },
  exitCode: 2,
  stdErr: 'unknown option --python\n' +
    'usage: /root/anaconda3/envs/sage/bin/python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...\n' +
    "Try `python -h' for more information.\n"
}
error 16:18:12.591: Failed to get activated conda env variables from Python for /root/anaconda3/envs/sage/bin/python
info 16:18:12.595: Process Execution: > ~/anaconda3/envs/sage/bin/python -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
> ~/anaconda3/envs/sage/bin/python -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"
info 16:18:12.763: Dispose Kernel '/path/to/ipynb' associated with '/same/path/to/ipynb'
```

Took a look at other similar kernel start problems, but the errors thrown were different (NOT one with 'unknown option --python', and the solutions implemented obviously did not work.

Please let me know if you need any more information to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - Edit the kernel.json file of the kernel and remove the `--python` option